# Sorting js files in web form

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can I know, the precedence of order in js files. I mean, If I have js files in order like show below doesn't work:

```
<link href="../design/css/ZoomImage/StyleZoom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../design/css/ZoomImage/imagezoom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../design/js/Smoothness/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../design/js/Smoothness/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../design/js/ZoomImage/jquery.imagezoom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<link href="../design/ivtCropping/css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../design/ivtCropping/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../design/ivtCropping/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../design/ivtCropping/js/jquery.cropzoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But if I have separete in distinct web form, it's works!!!

I need to integrate both in the same web form, but what is the rule to sort the js files?

The same happend if I use an user control, doesn't work.

Comment: The files are executed in the order they appear in the HTML.

Comment: why are embedding two version of jQuery ?

Comment: Sorry was I copy mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the Jquery and Jquery UI library at first and then rest.

You have two versions of jquery library (1.3.2 & 1.9.1) included which you shouldn't! Remove the older version jquery and retry.

Comment: Hi, Could you show me how?

Comment: You just need to remove this lines from your html <script src="../design/ivtCropping/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="../design/js/Smoothness/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: It's strange, because when I split first block in a web form and the other block in  other web form, work without issues, but when I put in the same web form failed. I retrieve the next below error: JQuery - Object [object Object] has no method

Comment: Thats right..when you put the two blocks in the same page, you are including two Jquery files and they must be conflicting. Did you try removing one of the jquery version when you put them in the same page?